# Not redirection. The page isn't redirecting properly. Translations in Refinerycms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, translation, refinerycms

I have a page in German name as 'kontakt', but the access is with /contact.
I start to fiy this bug, thinking in the translations and I did changes in:

(controller) inquiries-controller.rb: changing

```
  def find_page
    @page = ::Refinery::Page.find_by_link_url("/kontakt")
  end
```

The i18n.rb:

```
config.enabled = true
config.default_locale = :de
config.current_locale = :de
config.default_frontend_locale = :de
config.frontend_locales = [:en, :de]
config.locales = { :en => 'English', :de => 'Deutsch' }
```

I changed in (model)setting.rb:

```
def confirmation_subject(locale="de")...
```

instead of 'en'.

I changed the redirection in refinerycms to /kontakt.

I get the error ' The page isn't redirecting properly' in the browser.

The console:

> Started GET "/kontakt" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-19 17:07:27 +0100
>   Processing by Refinery::PagesController#show as HTML Parameters:
>   {"path"=>"kontakt", "locale"=>:de} Refinery::Role Load (0.2ms) SELECT
>   "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" WHERE
>   "refinery_roles"."title" = 'Refinery' LIMIT 1 Refinery::User Load
>   (0.2ms) SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" INNER JOIN
>   "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_users"."id" =
>   "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" WHERE
>   "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" = 1 Refinery::Page Load (0.4ms)
>   SELECT "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages" INNER JOIN
>   "refinery_page_translations" ON
>   "refinery_page_translations"."refinery_page_id" =
>   "refinery_pages"."id" WHERE "refinery_page_translations"."locale" IN
>   ('en', 'de') AND "refinery_page_translations"."slug" = 'kontakt' AND
>   "refinery_pages"."parent_id" IS NULL LIMIT 1 Redirected to
>   ../kontakt Refinery::User Load (0.1ms) SELECT
>   "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" WHERE "refinery_users"."id" =
>   3 LIMIT 1 Refinery::Role Load (0.1ms) SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM
>   "refinery_roles" INNER JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON
>   "refinery_roles"."id" = "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE
>   "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" = 3 Completed 302 Found in 8ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms) cache: [GET /kontakt] miss cache: [GET /kontakt]
>   miss

The log of development.log:

> Started GET "/kontakt" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-19 17:07:27 +0100
>   Processing by Refinery::PagesController#show as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"path"=>"kontakt", "locale"=>:de}   [1m[35mRefinery::Role Load
>   (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" WHERE
>   "refinery_roles"."title" = 'Refinery' LIMIT 1
>   [1m[36mRefinery::User Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT
>   "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" INNER JOIN
>   "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_users"."id" =
>   "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" WHERE
>   "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" = 1[0m   [1m[35mRefinery::Page
>   Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages"
>   INNER JOIN "refinery_page_translations" ON
>   "refinery_page_translations"."refinery_page_id" =
>   "refinery_pages"."id" WHERE "refinery_page_translations"."locale" IN
>   ('en', 'de') AND "refinery_page_translations"."slug" = 'kontakt' AND
>   "refinery_pages"."parent_id" IS NULL LIMIT 1 Redirected to
>   //../kontakt   [1m[36mRefinery::User Load
>   (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" WHERE
>   "refinery_users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1[0m   [1m[35mRefinery::Role Load
>   (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" INNER
>   JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_roles"."id" =
>   "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE
>   "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" = 3 Completed 302 Found in 6ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)

I have the translations in the files:
en.yml and de.yml

I have seen the information in http://refinerycms.com/edge-guides/translate-refinery
but I could not find a solution.

If I try to enter with /contact, works good, even with all of the changes.

Also, in the formular of the page, the validation is reading a value in english.

Comment: Could it be : `@page = ::Refinery::Page.find_by_link_url(t.contact)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on my website, and tried lots of different things to solve it. In the end, the simple solution worked. Try doing this:

Go to Plugins.
Select all - Tick Each Checkbox
Select deactivate
Test Website - It may or may not work
After this "Reactivate" all of the plugins.

Hopefully that fixes it. I tried doing this after lots of other things and it worked well! I wish I would of done this first.

Comment: What do you mean by "Go to Plugins"? Are you using some IDE?